# Android/Java. Как по событию OnBackPressed открыть Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, callback, android-navigation-drawer

Из Активити1 есть переход в Акт2. В Акт2 по событию OnBackPressed необходимо открыть Navigation Drawer.. Но он открывается и после этого сразу происходит переход на Активити1..

вопрос:
Как В Акт2 по событию OnBackPressed открыть Navigation Drawer и проигнорировать переход на Акт1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас отрабатывает строчка `super.onBackPressed();` Убедитесь в правильности условия (код для **открытия** `Navigation Drawer` при нажатии на `OnBackPressed`)

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Событие OnBackPressed можно поймать в activity. Там в зависимости от того какой  фрагмент лежит на вершине стека принимать решение об отправке onBackPressed() дальше по инстанциям.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if ((drawer != null) && (getTopActivity() instanceof xxxx) {
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```